# CMS For an Existing MVC6 App

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I have an MVC6 web site and am looking to simplify content management such as add an ability to edit content online instead of via HTML or database. It is possible to do this all manually via creating models, controlled and pages allowing to edit the data. But I'm afraid that it would be like inventing a bicycle.

Are there any tools that can be installed to an exising MVC6 app and add basic CMS functions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm building one, hoping to launch end of June.  I could let you have a preview of an MVC 5 version right now as I'm looking for feedback, but MVC 6 might be available late May early June if that is a suitable timescale.  The CMS is a series of NuGet libraries, and its clean, powerful and highly extensible.  One of the design priorities is for it to be straightforward to add to an existing site. Have a look at the first version of [the site for the CMS](http://www.lynicon.com)